# Add more tables to identity user in .NET Core 6

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity

I currently have a login done user `IdentityUser` with my own custom user table that links to the `AspNetUsers` table which I have called `CoreUser`:

```
public class CoreUser: IdentityUser<string>
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

The issue I am facing is that I want to link additional tables so I can called these properties from my user manager. I am trying to link a table called `Registrations` to the `User` table. The `User` table has a foreign key to the `Registration` table and I need to link additional tables to the `Registration` table. Meaning multiple tables have `RegistrationId` in them that I would like to link, I have linked these poco classes together.

For example, in my `User` class, I have this:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Registration ID")]
[ForeignKey("RegistrationId")]
public System.Guid RegistrationId { get; set; }
public virtual Registration Registration { get; set; }
```

And in my `Registration` class, I have the following

```
public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
public ICollection<VerificationAgency> Verifications { get; set; }
```

But for some reason, I always get null from `Registration` and so on. My `OnModelCreating` looks like this for my core user:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CoreUser>()
            .HasOne(a => a.User)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<User>(a => a.AspNetUsersId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CoreRole>();

        //Find and register anything implementing IEntityTypeConfiguration
        //https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

And then I have a variable which I created called logged in user, but the registration and other linking tables are always Null:

```
private User _loggedInUser;

protected User LoggedInUser
{
    get
    {
        if (_loggedInUser == null)
        {
            var userWhere = _userManager.Users
                                        .Where(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);

            _loggedInUser = userWhere.Select(user => user.User)
                                     .Include(x => x.Registration)
                                     .Include(x => x.Registration.Verifications)
                                     .FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return _loggedInUser;
    }
}
```

Am I missing a mapping or is it not possible to link extra tables to the user table. Here is an Image of my database for Some additional Context

[image: DB]

I have tried mapping everything on my `Registration` table, but it still doesn't seem to work

```
builder.HasMany(x => x.Users)
       .WithOne(x => x.Registration)
       .HasForeignKey(x => x.RegistrationId);

builder.HasMany(x => x.Verifications)
       .WithOne(x => x.Registration)
       .HasForeignKey(x => x.RegistrationId);
```